# JS: как сделать обращение к созданным элементам?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Доброе время суток!

Мне нужно добавлять элементы на страницу, а после работать с их полями. При добавлении (append, html) я выдаю им data.

Проблема заключается в том, что при событии изменении полей элемента, я не могу получить доступ к дата родителя. On change, bind не ловят элементы вообще. У меня получается ловить событие только такой конструкцией:

```js
$(document).on({
    change: function() {
    }
}, '.el');
```

Но при попытке обратиться к родителю

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().data("material-el-id")
```

или

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().data()
```

или

```
$(this).parent('.parentClass').data()
```

Мне прилетает только undefined.

Как получить data у родителя созданного элемента?

Оригинал:

```js
$('.add-material-btn').click(function () {
    loop1:
        for (i = 1; i <=5; i++){
            var type = getFromData('material-' + i + '-type');
            if (type == '' || type == null){
                $(".add-material-block-past").append('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 napolnenie-el" data-material-el-"' + i + '">'+$(".napolnenie-el-set" ).html()+'</div>');
                setDataAndText('material-' + i + '-type', 0);
                LAST_EDD_NAPOLNENIE_ID = i;
                break loop1;
            }
        }
});
$(document).on({
    change: function() {
        console.log(($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().data("material-el-id")));
    }
}, '.napolnenie-el-material');
```

Comment: потому что this это document, больше кода надо, логику по этому кусочку понять сложно.

Comment: Добавил код оригинала

Comment: весь нет смысла, там 7000 строк )

Comment: @VINET скиньте кусок html, а то структуры не понятно.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8cpr5h4y/

Comment: Не смотрел код, если правильно понял, то вот, например все ловится... http://codepen.io/rf150rus/pen/WGkGaZ?editors=1111

Comment: @sepgg, пожалуйста, напиши мне в скайпе v.a.stekolschikov, не работает так на реальном примере (((((((((

Comment: он про делегацию событий говорит, читайте тут http://api.jquery.com/on/